# Configure/Using FRAMEY callback for local rails development

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

Does anybody knows how to configure/use Framey (framey.com) callback to localhost:3000?

Hi configured my account to have the callback to localhost:3000 but it isn't working, at framey nobody answers me...

**Does anybody know any framey competitor?**
The ideia is to allow a user to upload his video directly from his desktop/laptop webcam. I'am using Rail 3.1.3 with carrierwave for file management on s3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Framey does not callback to localhost.
Instead create a dyndns/no-ip/something else to the development machine (or a IP address) and configure it in the account / callback.

Answer (score 0):

There is an answer on Framey's Get Satisfaction that might help:

https://getsatisfaction.com/framey/topics/callback_does_not_work_for_free_user